# How to play RTSP live video streams on VLC player?

Tags: windows-7, video, vlc-media-player, rtsp, rtmp

How can I play RTSP live video streams on VLC player? (v2.1.2 Rincewind, on Windows 7)

I can play RTMP live video streams, but not the RTSP streams.

I always get errors like this:

```
Connection failed:
VLC could not connect to "media2.lsops.net:554".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://media2.lsops.net/live/cnn_en_high.sdp'. Check the log for details.
----    

RTSP connection failed:
Access to the stream is denied by the server configuration.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://media4.lsops.net:80/bb/bbcnews_en_high.sdp'. Check the log for details.
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtmp://live0.seeon.tv/edge/1gb8fva4mwqr40j'. Check the log for details.
----

Connection failed:
VLC could not connect to "115.248.246.156:554".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://115.248.246.156:554/STARNEWS_QVGA.sdp'. Check the log for details.
Connection failed:
VLC could not connect to "115.248.246.156:554".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'rtsp://115.248.246.156:554/DISCOVERYSCINCE_QVGA.sdp'. Check the log for details.
```

Here is error log:

```
main debug: adding item `rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp' ( rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp )
qt4 debug: Adding a new MRL to recent ones: rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
main debug: processing request item: rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp, node: null, skip: 0
main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist
main debug: rebuild done - 1 items, index 0
main debug: starting playback of the new playlist item
main debug: resyncing on rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
main debug: rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp is at 0
main debug: creating new input thread
main debug: Creating an input for 'rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp'
main debug: meta ok for (null), need to fetch art
main debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path 'C:\Users\TL9\AppData\Local\Temp'
main debug: `rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp' gives access `rtsp' demux `' path `202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp'
main debug: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='' location='202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp' file='\\202.125.158.233:554\stream3_wifi.sdp'
main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 12 candidates
live555 debug: version 2013.12.05
main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any": 1 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\TL9\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher\tvrage.luac
main debug: using meta fetcher module "lua"
main debug: removing module "lua"
main debug: searching art for rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
main debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Users\TL9\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac
lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac
main debug: no art finder modules matched
main debug: art not found for rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
qt4 debug: IM: Setting an input
live555 debug: connection timeout
live555 error: Failed to connect with rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
main debug: no access_demux modules matched
main debug: creating access 'rtsp' location='202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp', path='\\202.125.158.233:554\stream3_wifi.sdp'
main debug: looking for access module matching "rtsp": 20 candidates
main debug: net: connecting to 202.125.158.233 port 554
main warning: connection timed out
access_realrtsp error: cannot connect to 202.125.158.233:554
access_realrtsp debug: could not connect to: 202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp
main debug: no access modules matched
main error: open of `rtsp://202.125.158.233:554/stream3_wifi.sdp' failed
main debug: finished input
main debug: dead input
main debug: changing item without a request (current 0/1)
main debug: nothing to play
qt4 debug: IM: Deleting the input
```